# Software for color blind people

Tags: browser-addons, css

I posted a question on [ui.stackexchange.com](http://ui.stackexchange.com), here: [Color Blindness, what can I do?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/color-blindness-what-can-i-do), but it dawned on me that question about software should probably be posed here.

So I'm asking.

Is there any software I can install in Windows 7 64-bit that would allow me to tweak the color-scheme of my monitor so that websites and other software designed for non-colorblind people would "pop" more?

For instance, I might want to tweak the red color to be more bright, or something like that.

Greasemonkey scripts or extensions to Google Chrome that gives me a bit more control would be nice as well. If I can make red links on white background go back to having underlines for some sites, that would be more than enough for me.

Comment: You can try Vision https://iristech.co/vision/
It performs real-time daltonization of the screen :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stylish should do everything you need: [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) or [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe). I'd also check out userstyles.org, the companion website, since I'm sure there are styles posted by/for colorblind people.

Comment: This fit the bill like a glove!

Answer (score 0):

I want to show you an extension which help coloblind people to see normal colors.
http://colorblind.tech/ this is the site of the extension  and this is direct link for the extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorblind-dalton/afcafnelafcgjinkaeohkalmfececool
Proven work